# c++: streaming and rate regulation

Tags: c++, network-programming

An interesting question I was asked in an interview:

Suppose you are constantly receiving some byte-stream from a source (let's assume a client-server model) with variable rate. You want to sort the packets on-the-fly at your end and retransmit them elsewhere at a constant rate. how would you implement such a system in C++?

I offered a basic system with a worker thread pushing packets into a heap and a dispatcher thread popping sorted packets and sending them away in sync with some internal clock in constant intervals of X.

The interviewer reasonably argued that such a system is prone to miss it's retransmission deadlines due to context switching between the threads. I replied that without any control of the thread scheduling algorithms in the specific machine, I can't guarantee constant retransmission rate. He followed with insistence that made me think that maybe I'm wrong and this is in fact achievable. So, am I?

Comment: I would add an extra step to recalculate remaining sleep time from actual slept time in transmitting thread. But I'n not aware of any real solution to meet real-time requirements on a time-sharing system.

Comment: This is a job for the token bucket algorithm, but it is also a job for a device driver, not an application program. Application programs can't meet real-time constraints, and neither for that matter can TC/IP, if that's what 'elsewhere' means. If you weren't interviewing for a kernel programming position the question was off topic.

Comment: @EJP I guess he was expecting me to mention the token bucket algorithm, as they (the company) also deal with video streaming, I knew that real-time wasn't possible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Description of the problem is too vague. What is meant by "sorting"? Do packets have some sort of sequence numbers in their bodies? What if we never receive packet with some sequence number? Here are my thoughts on some generic algorithm that may be adapted for different specific situations.

**Parameters**

Algorithm depends on following parameters:

1. Max number of packets we are allowed to buffer (e.g. 4096).
2. High watermark value. It is a percentage relative to (1). If we currently have more packets in buffer than HWV, then we send packet even if it is in not sorted order. (50%, or 2048).
3. TTL -- max time we allow our packet to be buffered.

**Variables**

First of all, we need a ring buffer of fixed length.
Ring buffer consists of:

1. Array[4096] of buffered packets
2. Array[4096] of pointers into above array (to avoid copying packets themselves during sort operation)
3. Array[4096] of meta-information for each packet: its sequence number (parsed from packet) and timestamp of when packet was received
4. Pointers to head and tail.

We also need to store global variable -- next sequence number to send.

**Algorithm**

When packet arrives, we add our packet into buffer to the proper position (one step of insertion sort), so our buffer is always sorted by sequence number. After that, we may want to send packet from head of buffer if at least one of the following is true:

1. Seq number of head packet is less or equal than expected seq number. This means that head packet is next in sorted order. Typical situation.
2. Number of packets in buffer exceeds high watermark value (2048). We send head packet (despite the fact that it is not in sorted order) because we are afraid that burst of incoming activity may fill the rest of our buffer and we will have to throw away further incoming packets.
3. Current time minus time of arrival of head packet exceeds TTL.

If at least one of above is true, we send head packet and remove it from buffer. We also assign expected sequence number to be seq number of sent packet plus one. If, after sending head packet, buffer is not empty, we also (re)start timer with TTL value. When timer is fired, we perform the very same above checks. This is to avoid keeping packets indefinitely in buffer (in case there are no more incoming packets).

Comment: Thanks. It was too vague because I've never heard the concept before, its now enough for me to get more familiar with it